# Missing Required Parameter in Parameterized Query?

Tags: c#, oledb, parameterized-query

I am getting the following error trying to execute the code below

***No Value Given For One Or More Required Parameters.***

```
string paraName = "CONTROL";
string fullPathToExcel = @"C:\Users\xbbjn2h\Desktop\Mapping.xlsx"; 
string connString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""",fullPathToExcel);
string sql = "SELECT [FUNCTION],[NAME] from [Sheet1$] WHERE [FUNTION] = ?";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connString;
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", paraName);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter dab = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    dab.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Double check your field and table names.  Something it probably misspelled.

Comment: It took a little time to view it, but you have a typo in your query. The field name is [FUNCTION] so you need to fix that name in the WHERE clause

Comment: Fixed it.  Thanks Steve!

Answer (score 0):

OleDbCommand does not support named parameters (see [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). What you need to do is something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = paraName });
```

Edit: I haven't tried it, but I suppose it might be possible to use your above code and pass null as the name argument...

Comment: While the docs are correct because they refer to the whole set of OleDb, I should point out that **OleDb using the ACE/JET provider** accepts named parameters. This doesn't mean that you can add parameters in any order. You still need to put them in the exact order in which they appear as placeholders in the commandtext.

Answer (score 0):

James, I can see that you are trying to parametrize as you would with `SQL`. However `OleDb` wouldn't follow the exact pattern. In `OleDb` you can simply put question marks in your sql sentence and fill them up later using `Parameter.Add().value` which is quite straight forward.

As MSDN reference points out:

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text.

I have rewritten your code in the way it should look like

```
    string paraName = "CONTROL";
    string fullPathToExcel = @"C:\Users\xbbjn2h\Desktop\Mapping.xlsx"; 
    string connString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""",fullPathToExcel);
    string sql = string.Format("SELECT [{0}],[{1}] from [{2}] WHERE [{0}] = ?", strFunction, strName, strSheetName);

    conn.ConnectionString = connString;
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Parameter.Add("@Param1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = paraName; // paraName or any value you wish.

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter dab = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd); //or cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); in Insert sql commands.
        dab.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        conn.Close();
    }
```

**Note**, You should put your `OleDbConnection` inside the `using` statement rather than your `OleDbCommand`.
I haven't tested it and it may contain some minor error. Other than that punch it there and press play (F5).

You can find more on `OleDb` parametrization from [OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Good luck and let us know what happens.